# slider automatically stop when slide reach to end in jcarousel

Tags: jquery

This is the for jcarousel slider. i am trying to make a non stop slider. here the problem is when slider reach the end slide it will automatically stopped. i need code for when slider reach a end means automatically start form beginning.

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.jcarousel').jcarousel();

        $('.jcarousel-control-prev')
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('inactive');
            })
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
                $(this).addClass('inactive');
            })
            .jcarouselControl({
                target: '-=1'
            });

        $('.jcarousel-control-next')
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('inactive');
            })
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
                $(this).addClass('inactive');
            })
            .jcarouselControl({
                target: '+=1'
            });

        $('.jcarousel-pagination')
            .on('jcarouselpagination:active', 'a', function() {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            })
            .on('jcarouselpagination:inactive', 'a', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            })
            .jcarouselPagination();



            $('.jcarousel').jcarouselAutoscroll({
            interval: 3500
           });

            $('.jcarousel').jcarouselAutoscroll({
            autostart: true
            });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You could use the setInterval() function.

Comment: slider image dynamically coming form database so how will use setinterval() function. can you please explain where will use the setinterval() function.

Comment: Nevermind, you have to do something with `target: '+=1'`. Should make it change to '1' if it reaches the end of the slides. I don't know how this slider works and I don't see the entire code of it, so I can't help you perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a documented issue by the jCarousel developer that wrap:circular is broken and won't be fixed until the next release.

https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/issues/search?q=circular

https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/issues/182

if it is fixed now try:

```
$('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
    wrap: 'both'
});
```

if does not work:

jCarouselLite has a continuous option, which may serve you better:

http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/

See also http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#doc and "circular' setting

Similar in many ways (and based on) jCarousel, but much more lightweight and pretty flexible.

Potential gotchya: If you scroll more than one item in continuous mode, it can skip some if the total number of items is not exactly divisible by the number you are scrolling.

Edit: Needless to say, I don't know for sure how to accomplish this using jCarousel if the `wrap: 'both'` is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
    $('#jcarousel').jcarousel({
        wrap: 'circular'
    });

        $('.jcarousel-control-prev')
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('inactive');
            })
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
                $(this).addClass('inactive');
            })
            .jcarouselControl({
                target: '-=1'
            });

        $('.jcarousel-control-next')
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('inactive');
            })
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
                $(this).addClass('inactive');
            })
            .jcarouselControl({
                target: '+=1'
            });

        $('.jcarousel-pagination')
            .on('jcarouselpagination:active', 'a', function() {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            })
            .on('jcarouselpagination:inactive', 'a', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            })
            .jcarouselPagination();



            $('.jcarousel').jcarouselAutoscroll({
            interval: 3500
           });

            $('.jcarousel').jcarouselAutoscroll({
            autostart: true
            });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: this is  working i put separate function $('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
             wrap: 'circular'
            });